# sorl thumbnail not created cache folder

Tags: python, django, image, thumbnails, sorl-thumbnail

I tried to use sorl thumbnail in django, i think i did everything good with configuration, but thumbnail is not created as well... My configuration

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('pages.urls')),
    path('galeria/', include('galleries.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'sorl.thumbnail',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Galeria'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Galerie'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
    
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos',default='')
    image = ImageField(upload_to='')
```

template

```
        {% for gallery in object_list %}
            <div class="gallery-photo-content">
                <h1 class='header'>#{{ gallery }}
                    {% thumbnail gallery.photos.all 'x300' crop="center" as im %}
                        <img src="{{ im.url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="">
                    {% endthumbnail %}
                </h1>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

and response 404 error

```
"GET /media/cache/b0/cb/b0cb61cf1f55b3a343fd939b5df40efb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 6194
```

[image]

I have no idea how to fix that problem.. Someone know how i did wrong?